# How can i change the ios app icon in flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a problem when i change the ios app icon in the flutter .

[This is my icon configuration list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptM41.png)

[This is my problem. The small icon cannot be replaced.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQoVj.png)

[However, the icon of the app has been changed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MN6sp.jpg)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to watch this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9ChjwrZqns&t=458s
It teaches how to change the `android` and `ios` icon.

Comment: In the same way, I don't know where the problem is

Answer (score 1):

you could change the icon automatically by using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

add the icon image to the assets folder,
then add this to your `pubspec.yaml` file

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.2"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon.png"
```

and run these commands in the terminal of your project

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

Comment: It's just that the small icon didn't work. I didn't try to use the plugin